# Count cycles from oscillator clock to get time

Tags: microcontroller, clock, timer, counter, gps

first time on stackexchange, hope I'm in the right place. I am working on a project where I need to timestamp an event (which will be detected from an electrical pulse) down to a few tens of nanoseconds and synchronized with GPS (because there will be a couple of those modules that need to be synced together). I looked for a simple arduino/raspberry solution but it seems it won't do better than 1-2 us, far from ~30 ns.

I was thinking of using the 1PPS output (1Hz) of the GPS to get a very accurate time and then find the time interval between this pulse and the sensor's pulse by counting cycles of an external, high precision clock. I have found a clock which will get me under 30ns innacuracy over the 1s PPS(40MHz, 10ppb, 1ps jitter).

Now, the problem is how do I go about counting these clock cycles? My experience on the subject is very close to 0 and so is my teammate's. Any help is very much appreciated.

EDIT: It seems this is very complicated for someone who's only experience with microcontroller is sending data through serial. The perfect product for my application would be something like this: http://www.ti.com/product/TDC7201/description Just connect the two pulses to START and STOP pins and it returns the time interval. The only difference is I would need a 1s measurement (vs 8ms) but with 10-50ns precision (vs 50ps). Basically 1000x longer measurement with 1000x less precision.

Comment: An ATmega328 (the microcontroller in an arduino uno) can time events down to 62.5 ns resolution, not "1 or 2 microseconds".

Comment: I think what you want to do is run your processor from the 40 MHz clock, and use an internal timer to measure the interval. The 1PPS signal may not be accurate when the GPS is not synced to satellites. Also, the 1pps signal may have a slow rise or fall time, and this could introduce some timing uncertainty if your switching voltage threshold is not very stable. If I remember correctly, the 1pps is stable in the long term, but may have cycle-to-cycle jitter. So the ideal solution might be some kind of digital PLL.

Comment: The GPS does have jitter (11 ns for the one I have in mind). The GPS is a must since we need 5 synced modules separated by about 10km.

Can you elaborate on "run your processor from the 40 MHz clock, and use an internal timer to measure the interval"? I have read about the 62.5 ns resolution of ATmega by counting cpu cycles but I haven't managed to find how to count it. Even then, the onboard clock doesn't have the required precision (will lose/advance much more than 30ns over 1s).

Comment: @jms, OP means 30ns absolute error over 1 s time interval. The junky arduino clock is likely 50ppm, which will give you 50us error.

Comment: First you want a "GPS disciplined oscillator" unless you are going to try to emulate that in software by applying corrections from the number of clocks you have measured per GPS Hz.   Your timing resolution requirements may stress typical MCU counter/timer peripheral clock limits - both because high internal clocks are multiplied internally from a lower input, and because often the peripherals can't run at the full rate. But look at various modern ARM Cortex M4 parts to get an idea of what would be easy.  To go faster you might consider an FPGA for the timestamping and MCU to report.

Comment: What I mean is, if the processor runs from a high accuracy oscillator, such as your 40 MHz clock, then the other clocks inside the processor will have the same accuracy, even if the frequency is different due to PLL's and up/down conversion using dividers/multipliers, etc. Many processors have time capture functions built into them, where a certain event starts the timer, and another event stops it. Then it is just a matter of reading the register after the event occurs. Not sure it can hit your target, but if not, then you may need an FPGA.

Comment: @ChrisStratton "try to emulate that in software by applying corrections from the number of clocks you have measured per GPS Hz" If I understand correctly, this is what I am trying to do. The question remains, how do I count the number of clock cycles between 2 events (or electric pulses)?

Comment: You use the counter/timer peripheral in a better MCU than an ATmega, or if you need to go faster than that you use a small FPGA or a dedicated timing chip - it sounds like you want an event timer clocked at 100 MHz or so.  The software corrections idea would be to also measure the interval of the GPS 1pps, and apply any deviations from a measured second there to the measured times of the events of interest, under some simple model of the error of the fast local clock.  That will be crude, but cheaper than using a GPS disciplined 100 MHz or so lab source.

Comment: If you are using code, you fetch the count from a free-running timer whose frequency is known. If you are using capture registers, you set them up correctly, then just read the elapsed time from the appropriate register after the event has occurred. I am not a programmer, but I do deal with this kind of stuff sometimes.

Comment: Some GPS chipsets have a Pulse Input pin, the module  tells you the time that it changes state. Dig through the uBlox product range. For GPS to reliably reach sub-100 ns will need a long measuring time, or a fancy ionofree receiver. For calibration you'll need access to a better reference unit, and a time interval counter. You might be lucky with several units of the same model, easy to test.

Comment: @tomnexus The GPS I had in mind was from uBlox actually (https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/UBX-G6010-ST-TM_ProductSummary_%28GPS%20G6-HW-11034%29.pdf). You made me notice that it features "Time mark of external event inputs". Will this be reliable? They state that the RMS accuracy is 30ns, should that be valid for marking an event at the input?

Comment: @user126881 that's the feature I was referring to. I think you won't do better than that. For accuracy, 30 ns is right on the limit of what a simple GPS can do anyway, timing at that level is dominated by the ionosphere. And it saves all that circuit design pain.

Comment: @user126881 you'll still have lots of issues with such a fast input. For example, I have a raspberry pi measuring something using a GPS PPS output as a trigger. I find that it is often false-triggered by electrical noise. So I find 11 or 12 pulses every 10 seconds. I will need a much better ground and shielding to stop this.

Comment: @tomnexus I contacted u-blox today and everyone of their module can do it, even if it is not always mentionned as a feature. For people who might wonder, u-blox modules can timemark an event once every epoch, so once per second for a 1Hz update rate. If two events happen in an epoch, only the last will be timemarked.

Comment: @tomnexus That ublox can run at 5Hz so that gets you to 1 event every 200ms. The other option if you need more frequent events is to run the PPS at a faster rate. All ublox can do at least 1kHz on the PPS. That reduces the maximum time you need to count on a different clock to 1ms max which should reduce errors. Know the absolute time for each PPS pulse requires some playing around during initialization but is doable.

Answer (score 1):

Counting cycles between PPS pulses is not a good approach. Even using clocks with 10ppb stability, you still need to evaluate the skew between different units.

Using an integrated GPS Receiver with timestamping is a good approach. Note however that it will not be easy to get these 30ns RMS accuracy in real life conditions. 30ns translate to only 9m position accuracy. While most receivers reach this easily for kalman filtered position, you will see more disturbance to your timestamps (where the receiver cannot employ a [hidden markov model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model)) unless you also average over multiple events.

Multipath reception is your main adversary (for units some tens of km apart and events within fractions of a second). Multipath will be mitigated somehow by the receiver, but the best thing you can do is use a good antenna (choke ring or similar) and choose a good place. Putting it on a tripod can also help.

Group delay calibration will typically not be needed for 30ns if all your modules use a similar Setup (antenna cable length matters, also amplifiers or similar).

Far better accuracy can be reached if you are able to measure the event *in band* with the GPS Signals, that means *trough the RF frontend of the reveiver*. This will relate the timing directly to the received signals and offers the opportunity to cancel off several error sources. If you do not need the result in near real time, you may record GPS signals together with your trigger and postprocess them. This will give high accurary of relative position and time (differential GPS).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Arduino Uno, but it probably has a counter module that can time intervals. But it will be limited to the clock frequency, which is probably too low for what you want. You'd better switch to an Arduino Due, it surely has this capability and can run at 96 MHz. Study the counter/timer peripheral (datasheet). Use it to capture

- the interval between the 1s pulses
- the interval between the last 1s pulse and the event

From these figures you can calculate the accurate interval between the last pulse and the event.

Note that programming the peripheral is not easy. And if your experience in micro-controller programing is zero, you'll first have to get it to a reasonable level. That is not something you learn in a week. If you have basic programming skills and a good instructor a month might be a good guess. And understanding the timer comes after that..

Answer (score 0):

I worked with an R&D co. that once had a network with similar requirements for synchronous TDM on a shared network.  The upstream Multiplexor measured the phase error of a narrow pulse from each "sender" so that not only could the downstream targets be phase locked to the shared bit stream in their own time slot, but phase synchronized due to "Line buildout" or latency or any other phase error. The repeater then sent phase correction commands to each sender when needed to ensure the central point received all in perfect sync.

In order to accomplish anything like this your phase error detector must have greater resolution than the error required and the drift over time of any unsynchronized sender must translate into a time interval that can be corrected within the phase detector span of +/- xx ns. Using ULF/VLF phase detection such as gives greater phase span but when multiplied up to resolution of frequency that gives phase sync in the 10ns region requires either a very stable low phase noise clock or high channel bandwidth.

WWVB is very stable <1e-12 in f but inadequate bandwidth to correct better than a few ms due to 60kHz carrier with a few kHz Bw.  Translate this up to ns and your network bandwidth to correct phase errors must be 1e6 higher in frequency.

Start with accurate specs on requirements for each location and determine your phase accuracy that you can achieve in detecting phase error in ns. **I doubt any Arduino can resolve this without specialized interface hardware to measure phase error in nanoseconds.**

I have designed many different Doppler instruments from VLF to UHF so I am just dealing in generalities here.

Comment: I agree nanonseconds would be out of the question (that would require a ~ 1 GHz clock), but a 96 MHz Due should be able to reach 10's of nanoseconds.

Comment: I think a 500MHz Cortex might be better suited.

Comment: Maybe easier, but it might be overkill, and not as easily available. (The Due has a Cortex-M3).